# Which airlines servicing Asia have staff trained in self-defense?

Tags: air-travel, safety, asia

I read in a [recent news article](http://www.smh.com.au/world/a-hazing-ritual-forced-chinese-female-flight-attendants-into-overhead-bins-20151013-gk8f5e.html) that at Hong Kong airlines, staff have to master kung fu.

Although I'm aware that passengers grabbing control of the cockpit is no longer possible, there's other incidents involving violence by passengers (eg [this one](http://news.yahoo.com/3-month-sentence-japan-hawaii-flight-assault-204745365.html)), so all things being equal, I'd prefer to have staff who are capable of protecting themselves and passengers from other passengers. Which airlines servicing the Asia region have staff trained in self-defense?

Comment: Violence in airplanes is _very_ rare.  I would not select an airline knowing if they have training in self defense.

Comment: I imagine you're more likely to be struck by lightning on your way to the airport, than you are to be attacked by a fellow passenger.

Comment: BTW the star of HK airline, Rose Chan, who was known as kung fu actress, was being indecent assult in 2011

Comment: Self defense training for crew is going to be mandatory in the coming years. I am am insider and I know this.

Comment: @Nean I know you have a sense of humour, so I'd like to check - was that a joke, or serious?

Comment: @andrew I am serious and I will prove it tomorrow.

Comment: Self-defence and martial arts stuff is really not all it's cut out to be in the films. Also I would question whether anyone can really "master" anything like that unless they dedicate their life to it. Maybe a year or two of training improves your odds in a fight a bit but all it really taught me was to avoid getting into a fight with a larger, better armed or more numerous opponent at all costs.

Comment: From what I can see on Google this was a publicity stunt.

Comment: (+1) I tend to agree with @Max but then it's your question and it's clear and on-topic.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis ping.

Answer (score 3):

EL AL

They have [undercover staff carrying firearms](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/americas/2097352.stm) on every international flight, moreover the pilots are usually [former pilot of Israel Air Force](http://forward.com/sisterhood/137646/with-yom-haatzmaut-festivities-a-gender-barrier-is/).

Comment: We're gonna need references for these claims. ;)

Comment: This answers my question, but I'm not a big fan of "gun fu".